# Apache - How to define PHP 5.6 as the PHP version of a subdomain

Tags: php, apache

The scenario is this:

I have an Apache server running PHP 5.5.

I need to deploy a new framework that requires PHP 5.6, but i need to keep the old framework running for a few months (App old releases).

The problem is (after installing PHP 5.6), when i run:

```
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Some of old end-poins stop working, and i don't have time to support the PHP versions issues of the old framework, so i think the solution is run the new framework on the 5.6 and keep the other one running.

I think i have to add some config on /etc/apache2/sites-available/some.conf to run PHP 5.6 but i don't know what to put here.

Any help ?

Comment: Go through this:https://www.sitepoint.com/run-multiple-versions-php-one-server/

Comment: I do not think you can run 2 php versions on a single Apache webserver, especially if it is using mod_php, because php extension for apache has paths to php executables and that is done at lower leven than your v-host. (and please correct me if I am wrong).  You may have better luck if you use php fpm as that allows to specify php parsers at vhost level, so maybe you could create 2 php services and use them for your vhosts. Or use nginx as your wbserver